# Should I use a graphics engine or do the low level graphics myself?

Tags: education

Programming is more of a hobby for me right now as I'm still in highschool. When I get to college I plan to make it less of a hobby and more of a profession. But for now what would you guys suggest for making a 3D game in c++ (not c++11)? Should I learn and do the low level graphics myself or just use a graphics engine like Ogre while I learn the other aspects of making a game, or just use a full game engine?

My goal would be to learn. I want to learn how to do the lower level stuff such as graphics, physics, AI, ect. but I'm not sure if I should jump right into graphics or do the other stuff first.

I am currently taking the highest level math I can at my school (calculous) and might end up taking a c++ class at my local community college for a semester this year if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GameDev.SE. Questions about how to start or which technology to use are considered off-topic here. And with all questions of this type the only advice I can give is: Learn and use what you're interested in. If you want to make a Game, use existing libraries that will allow you to write a game instead of a graphics-engine.. if you want to write a graphics-engine, well, then do that :)

Comment: that makes sense. and sorry for the mislabeling

Comment: The reason this question might be off topic is that answers will most likely be opinion based. We don't know what's best for you. I'd suggest testing the water using both approaches, and see what interests you. For example, try making a simple game in GameMaker/RPG Maker, or programming your own BMP reader/writer, for starters.

Comment: My opinion: [Write games, not engines](http://scientificninja.com/blog/write-games-not-engines). By using an existing engine you can concentrate fully on the gameplay and content while saving most of the low-level work. Unless you have very unusual requirements, you will just reinvent the wheel by writing your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide you some advice nevertheless, I recommend to start with low level graphics programming.

There are a handful of great OpenGL beginner tutorials out there on the internet. It is not that hard to learn the basics yourself without having worked with third party engines before.

The math behind isn't that challenging, and you even took a high level course at school. Programming experience in C++ is a big plus. I would advice people who haven't worked in C++ before, to first learn the language and after that dive into graphics programming. Trying to handle both at the same time might be hard.

Depending on your interests, you could later on change to an engine like Unity which handles graphics for you, so that you can focus on your other fields of interest. That is not necessary if you're coding for learning and fun, since at that point you will already have built a working renderer system on your own. But if you consider releasing the project as a game, you could benefit from the increased graphics provided by such an engine.

By the way, what is wrong with C++11? It brings some really handy tools, like futures, lambdas, filesystem access, and more, which can increase productivity also in game development a lot.

Comment: the only issue i have with c++11 is that i started programming with xbox homebrew and the latest 'leak' of the xbox360 sdk only supports vs2010 which doesn't support c++11. honestly it wouldn't be that big of a deal to just use c++11 but for some reason i like having the option of being able to port the game to the 360 platform for my smc hacked console. i got a couple simple 2d games working on my xbox but 3d seems like a who different world to me. also xbox only supports directx i believe so i'll probably use directx, if i decide to transition to c++11 i'll look into opengl.

Comment: thanks for your input though, i think i might actually look into c++11 and opengl seeing how the xbox platform looks like it would be really difficult to jump into with it's low memory.

Comment: DirectX is fine in your case, too. It is just that OpenGL is open and cross-plattform, and I therefore recommend it. By the way, if you should decide against C++11 later on, for programming on your console, you should definitely take a look at the boost library.